# c++ QT How to run a function when a button is clicked and how to replace the button?

Tags: c++, qt, button, replace, onclick

I'm new to c++ qt... and I have 2 problems:(

I have this code:

```
QPushButton *m_button= new QPushButton ("Start Testing", this) ;
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(m_button,150,150, 100,140);
m_button->show();
```

and  I have this function:

```
void StartToSendCommand(QString fileName, QPlainTextEdit *textEdit)//Ruth
{
    QFile file(fileName);
     if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
         return;

     QTimer * inputTimer=new QTimer(textEdit);
     QTextStream in(&file);
     QString line;
     while (!in.atEnd()) {
         line = in.readLine();
         if (line==""||line[0]=="#")
             continue;
         for(int i=0; i< line.length(); ++i)
         {
             qDebug()<<line[i];
             QThread::sleep(1);

         }
         qDebug()<<"END OF COMMANDS";
         inputTimer->start(GWaitingTimeBetweenCommand);
         QApplication::processEvents();
         QThread::sleep(2);


     }
}
```

How can I run the function when a button is clicked?
and another problem, how can \i place the button, for example in the middle of the window? I use it:

```
QGridLayout *layout = new QGridLayout(this);
layout->addWidget(m_button,150,150, 100,140);
```

but its not help... and do nothing
can anyone help me?

thanks!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using the UI editor to create your UI? Have you read about signals and slots?

Comment: I used it, I choose the application- but i have to add this button... I try to read and didnt  understand what I Supposed to do...:(

Comment: I have tyied to read them before but I didnt understand... its not connected to the button.. or that I really dont understand...:(

Comment: thank for your help, I succeed:)                                                                                           I would appreciate an answer to my second question :)

Comment: @AlanBirtles There is probably about 100 reasons why not to use UI editor to create the UI. Firstly it is extremely clumsy, you often end up fiddling with crazy 1px precise placing of items in layouts. Changing a hierarchy of existing layouts is a nightmare. It does not allow conditional compilations (analogy to C++ ifdefs). It does not allow comments. A single change often completely breaks the hierarchy in the UI file resulting in impossible to handle diffs and merges. And many many more problems... QtDesigner is probably the worst part of the whole Qt framework.